# Google Apps Script MailApp.sendEmail sending a copy to inbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Script sends Email to recipient but I find **two** copys in my Gmail Inbox and my Gmail Sent folder. I only want 1 copy in my **sent folder** not in my **inbox folder**!

```
    MailApp.sendEmail("recipient@recipient.com", "Subject", "", 
    {htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent() + message1 + message2)}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue. I don't have myself in the To field but I'm getting a copy. I should only be seeing these emails in the Sent folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Gmail behaviour. Any email sent via your email account, whether through the Gmail website or the Gmail API, will be saved in your Sent items folder.

Comment: yes, correct. I am fine with saving the message in my Sent folder. But it is also saving it in my Inbox when I use MailApp to send Emails.